# SASS/SCSS mixin for anchor &:hover is not working

Tags: css, button, sass, hover

I have this code:

```
 @mixin fade-transition($element) {
    -webkit-transition: $element 0.15s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: $element 0.15s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: $element 0.15s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: $element 0.15s ease-in-out;
    transition: $element 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

body {
  background: grey;
  font-family: "Arial";
  background-size: cover;
}

a {

  display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    color: #FAFAFA;
    border: 3px solid #FAFAFA;
    padding: 25px;

    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    @include fade-transition(background);

    &:hover {
        background: rgba(8,97,76,0.6);
    }
}
```

It's just the part of the code, when I hover the button nothing happens. I know that the :&hover line is not recognized but why is that? I wasn't able to see what's wrong

Thank you for your time.

Comment: works fine in sassmeister: http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/7923dcb635843326108ed3514703e0fb. Check HTML in view menu

Comment: Doesn't work for me, any other way?

Comment: SCSS Mixins works fine at JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/itsselvam/hLxgchx6/. Can you share the HTML code part?

Comment: Only the hover doesn't work for me, is the problem may be that I'm using visual studio 13?

Comment: Can you add your css output?

Comment: I can't because I copied it manually to a pc without internet connection

Comment: The examples in sassmeister and jsfiddle don't work for you?

Comment: I can't copy them

Comment: You don't have to copy nothing, only see the examples, the code is yours

Comment: It works just fine It doesn't work on VS13

Comment: I don't think the editor is the problem. Possibly another style is overwriting the `hover` or something is wrong in your html or in other part of your css

Comment: The code works, the issue is something other than the .scss code.
It is possible that you aren't building the .css file, or you aren't importing the .css correctly into the .html file that you want to see the a:hover reflected on. Ensure that you your .css file is being loaded, the editor shouldn't make any difference at all.